# TYPO3: automatically cache new entries in extension

Tags: plugins, full-text-search, typo3

I created a new extension using the kickstarter and everything works just as expected, but one of the core requirements that this extension needs to have is that every entry (single view) is searchable using indexed search.
The data is stored in a sys folder and imported via CSV directly into the database, which leads to the problem that none of those new pages are searchable because they are not cached.

Is there a way to automatically cache every single view so it can be searched? I tried using the crawler extension, but failed to understand how I would set it up correctly, it just goes beyond my understanding of TYPO3. It is loaded as a USER object and caching is on.

```
t3lib_extMgm::addPItoST43($_EXTKEY, 'pi1/class.tx_zebsem_pi1.php', '_pi1', 'list_type', 1);
```

It all works nicely if I create a new entry and just visit this entry so it is cached, then it is searchable, but I simply cannot go through 500 or more entries every time a new CSV is imported. The cHash is also set correctly. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the Frontend-URL you can call the SingleView with PHP (file_get_contents ..).
You will get Problems with the PHP-Script-Runtime-Timeout. But this may be changeable with .htaccess only for the Import-Script (Folder).

Comment: I see where you're going with this, it seems to be all about just calling the pages instead of having a real solution. The best thing I found so far is a cronjob with wget...

Comment: Yes it´s the easiest solution and i dont know a negative side-effect. 
In fact you can also do a error-check of the generated page if you trigger caching this way ..

Comment: I will use this solution then. Maybe some day I'll find one that involves native Typo3 functions. Thank you.